# how to custome change tig text color on iTerm?

Tags: tig

I have installed tig, and confirmed installation successful. why in my `~/`directory don't have `.tigrc` file?

How can I configure tig?

Answer (score 2):

You could download [the default configuration file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonas/tig/master/tigrc) to `~/.tigrc` and edit it.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer (the green tick) if it solves your problem.